# How to monitor state of Java applications running on different machines using zookeeper?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

How to monitor state of Java standalone applications running on different machines using zookeeper?. If any of the java application is not running / shutdown / killed, a notification should be sent or some event should trigger.

Ex : My java program(Sample.java) running in nohup mode on Machine A, B, C and in any case, program is killed on Machine A. How would we know the program on machine A is shutdown/got killed. Any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading a few specific parts of the Apache ZooKeeper documentation:

[Ephemeral Nodes](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/zookeeperProgrammers.html#Ephemeral+Nodes): A process can create an ephemeral znode, and this znode will be deleted automatically if that process fails to maintain its ZooKeeper session, such as if the process terminates abnormally.

[Group Membership](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/recipes.html#sc_outOfTheBox): This describes a recipe for implementing group membership by using ephemeral znodes.  A parent znode acts as a container representing the group, and each individual process creates an ephemeral znode under that parent znode.  Since ephemeral znodes will be deleted automatically on process death, the current list of children under the parent znode accurately represents the list of processes currently alive.

[ZooKeeper Watches](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkWatches): A monitoring application could use the ZooKeeper API to set a watch on the parent znode representing the group.  It will receive notifications when new child znodes are created or deleted under the parent.  The monitoring application could have logic in a callback to trigger an alert (send an e-mail, toggle from green to red in a web UI, etc.) when a process's ephemeral znode gets deleted.

Additionally, you might find the Apache Curator project useful as a utility API over calling the ZooKeeper API directly.  Curator's [Group Member](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/group-member.html) recipe might be a good fit for your needs.